# Cannot pass Proxy trying to get acces token for google service

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, http-proxy

I am trying to consume an API but first i have to get an access token from Google.

My code looks like this:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Http;
```

....

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream("my_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var cred = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(new[] { "my_scope" });

    var httpClientHandler = new ConfigurableMessageHandler(NetworkManager.Instance.GetHttpProxyHandler());
    var httpClient = new ConfigurableHttpClient(httpClientHandler);

    cred.UnderlyingCredential.Initialize(httpClient);
    var token = await cred.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
}
```

Since we have a proxy server in our environment, i have to pass the proxy credentials.
I have built my own class NetworkManager, where i can create the ProxyHandler. It works with HTTPClient and other service requests very well but not in this case.

So what i have tried is to call the "Initialize" method of the "UnderlyingCredential" Object, so that i can pass a HttpClient with the configured ProxyHandler.

But when i try to get the Token (Last line) then i become an error message:

> The proxy tunnel request to proxy 'http://proxy-server-ip' failed
> with status code '407

Is there an other way to configure the proxy settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved my problem with the following code:

```
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("proxy-host", false, null, new NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>"));
Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = HttpClientFactory.ForProxy(proxy);

using (var stream = new FileStream("my_secret", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var scopes = new string[] { "my_scope" };
    var cred = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes).CreateWithHttpClientFactory(httpClientFactory);
    var token = await cred.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
}

return true;
```

I found the answer of amanda-tarafa from github: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1864

If anyone else faces the same problem.